# Map legacy htm files to equivalent action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was trying to do the following:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
    {
        //other stuff
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyRoute", 
            url: "test.htm", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Test" });
    }
}
```

But IIS returns a 404 as it tries to retrieve the static file of `example.com/test.htm`.

How can I get the desired effect?

Comment: Additionally I have tried putting this at the top of the `RegisterRoutes` method. Still with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me in the end was to do the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="htm to asp" path="*.htm" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because MVC routing has a hard time with periods. If you are using .NET 4 you can put

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
```

in your web.config file.

Here is an explanation and more info: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx